# VirtualBox has to compile on every boot

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox

I have to compile VirtualBox on every boot manually by running `sbin/vboxconfig.sh` otherwise, it doesn't run what's a permanent solution to this problem?. My kernel version is `4.4.0-72`.

```
    srseven@srseven-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~/genymotion/tools$ dkms status
    bcmwl, 6.30.223.248+bdcom, 4.4.0-64-generic, x86_64: installed
    bcmwl, 6.30.223.248+bdcom, 4.4.0-66-generic, x86_64: installed
    bcmwl, 6.30.223.248+bdcom, 4.4.0-70-generic, x86_64: installed
    bcmwl, 6.30.223.248+bdcom, 4.4.0-71-generic, x86_64: installed
    bcmwl, 6.30.223.248+bdcom, 4.4.0-72-generic, x86_64: installed
    rtlwifi-new, 0.10~trusty, 4.4.0-64-generic, x86_64: installed (original_module exists)
    rtlwifi-new, 0.10~trusty, 4.4.0-66-generic, x86_64: installed (original_module exists)
    rtlwifi-new, 0.10~trusty, 4.4.0-70-generic, x86_64: installed (original_module exists)
    rtlwifi-new, 0.10~trusty, 4.4.0-71-generic, x86_64: installed (original_module exists)
    rtlwifi-new, 0.10~trusty, 4.4.0-72-generic, x86_64: installed (original_module exists)
    srseven@srseven-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ dpkg -l *virtualbox*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
un  virtualbox     <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  virtualbox-5.1 5.1.18-11400 amd64        Oracle VM VirtualBox
un  virtualbox-gue <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-gue <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-ose <none>       <none>       (no description available)
```

Comment: Installing it directly from Ubuntu repositories or using Virtuabox's PPA always worked for me and never had to compile. Any special reason why you installed it that way? And, of course, you should edit the question and describe *how* exactly have you installed it in the first place.

Comment: installed it by downloading the deb from Virtualbox site.

Comment: I just tested in a machine without it, downloading and installing the deb as you supposedly did. Opened it, closed it, rebooted and opened again. Everything is working *comme il faut*. You must have done something else.

Comment: If you got the file from _oracle_ then something is wrong, that's not a  normal behaviour. Check that the version you downloaded is the correct one!

Comment: i downloaded the trusty version.

Comment: In `terminal`, edit your question to include the output of `dkms status` and `dpkg -l *virtualbox*`. Make sure to add `@heynnema` at the beginning of comments directed to me, or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I have included the outputs of the commands you asked.

Comment: the output is after a fresh boot and before running  `sbin/vboxconfig` script.

Comment: Please redo the `dpkg -l *virtualbox*` command, as you forgot the *'s. Please do this AFTER you reinstall Virtualbox (as it doesn't appear to be installed right now). Thanks.

Comment: ps: What version of Ubuntu are you running? Trusty? 14.04? Are you running with the stock kernel, or have you upgraded it?

Comment: @heynnema output of command `dpkg -l *virtualbox*` after reinstalling VirtualBox and yeah I am running trusty 14.04 with the updated kernel 4.4.0-72.

Comment: @heynnema also upvote my question.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments...

You're running Trusty/14.04 with an updated kernel 4.4.0-72. You've installed:

http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.1.18/virtualbox-5.1_5.1.18-114002~Ubuntu~trusty_amd64.deb

which doesn't match your kernel. Did you also install the newer "linux-extras" .deb and the newer "linux-headers" .deb? If not, install them, or downgrade to the stock kernel from the Trusty distribution.

You can also GRUB boot to the prior original Trusty kernel, if you've kept it around.

If you keep your current kernel, you'll need to install a newer version of VirtualBox, probably this one:

http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.1.18/virtualbox-5.1_5.1.18-114002~Ubuntu~xenial_amd64.deb.